Duda con instancia de la conexión MySql en PHP
Me ayudaron a mejorar una clase que uso para conectar MySql con PHP y quedo de la siguiente forma, que cabe mencionar que funciona todo bien.
class Database
{

    private static $db_host     = "localhost";
    private static $db_user     = "elUsuario";
    private static $db_password = "123";
    private static $db_database = "laBD";

    /*
        Propiedad que representa la conexión
    */
    private static $mysqli;

    static function conexion()
    {
        /*
            Activamos el manejo de errores
            Obsérvese que en los  métodos usamos
            bloques try ... catch
            y que relanzamos la Exception con throw new Exception($e)
            lo cual permitirá capturar cualquier error en el llamador
            por eso podemos quitar todos los if que había
        */
        $driver = new mysqli_driver();
        $driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
        try
        {
            self::$mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
            self::$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
            self::$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
            return self::$mysqli;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "No se pudo conectar a la BD";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function select($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $result = self::$mysqli->query($query);
            if(isset($result->num_rows))
            {
                if($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    $rows = self::resultToArray($result);
                    $result->free();
                    return $rows;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "Error SQL: $query";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function insert($query)
    {
        try
        {
            self::$mysqli->multi_query($query);
            $insert_id = self::$mysqli->insert_id;
            return $insert_id;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "Error SQL: $query";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function update($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $success = self::$mysqli->query($query);
            return $success;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->__toString());
            echo "Error SQL: $query";
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    static function resultToArray($result)
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /*
        Redefinición de métodos, para poder llamarlos
        desde cualquier parte....
        Lo mejor es que la clase extienda de Mysqli
    */
    static function begin_transaction($type)
    {
        self::$mysqli->begin_transaction($type);
    }

    static function commit()
    {
        self::$mysqli->commit();
    }

    static function rollback()
    {
        self::$mysqli->rollback();
    }

    static function close()
    {
        self::$mysqli->close();
    }
}

Pero me comentan que esta clase se puede mejorar extendiendola de la clase MySqli para asi no tener que redifinir ciertas funciones que posee dicha clase como: commit, rollback, etc.
Estuve analizando una respuesta que me compartieron de otra pregunta y me surge una duda en cuanto a la conexión a la base de datos, el código que veo en esa respuesta es el siguiente:
class DbMySqli extends mysqli{
    private $host="localhost";
    private $user="root";
    private $pass="";
    private $bd="libros";
    private static $mMysqli;
    
    // Constructor
    public function __construct() {     
        parent::__construct($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->bd);
        
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("Error de conexión MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(),
            E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    } 

    /*
       Obtener la instancia de la conexión
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { 
        /*
            Si no hay instancia, crea una
        */
            self::$mMysqli = new self();
        }
        self::$mMysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        return self::$mMysqli;
    }

    ......
}

En cuestión del constructor no hay duda pero luego veo la función getInstance() y ahí es donde me empiezan los problemas. ¿Para que la creación de esa función? ¿Es necesario crearla?
$conexion = new DbMySqli();

Qué no se supone que al instanciar la clase hija, se hereda atributos, funciones y demás información de la clase padre??
Yo pensaría que en el objeto $conexion se tendría la conexión de la base de datos y ya no vería el caso de la función getInstante()
ACTUALIZACIÓN
He modificado mi código de acuerdo a lo que he investigado y me han respondido.
Class.Database.php
<?php
class Database extends mysqli
{
    private $db_host     = "localhost";
    private $db_user     = "root";
    private $db_password = "123";
    private $db_database = "empresabd";
    private static $dbMysqli;
    
    function __construct()
    {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
        parent::__construct($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_password, $this->db_database);
    }
    
    public function select($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $result = $this->query($query);
            if(isset($result->num_rows))
            {
                if($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    $rows = $this->resultToArray($result);
                    $result->free();
                    return $rows;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    public function insert($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->multi_query($query);
            $insert_id = $this->insert_id;
            return $insert_id;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    public function update($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $success = $this->query($query);
            return $success;
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e)
        {
            throw new Exception($e);
        }
    }

    public function resultToArray($result)
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    private function __clone(){ }
    
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!self::$dbMysqli)
        { 
            self::$dbMysqli = new self();
        }
        
        self::$dbMysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        self::$dbMysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
        return self::$dbMysqli;
    }
}
?>

Ahora la duda viene con las funciones que implemento en la clase Usuario y que son llamadas en este caso desde el archivo insert.php
Actualmente tengo así los códigos de la clase y el archivo:
class.Usuario.php
<?php    
include_once("class.Database.php");
    
    class Usuario 
    {
        public $id_usuario;
        public $nombre;
        public $apellidos;
        public $usuario;
        public $contrasena;
        
        function __construct($id_usuario)
        {
            global $conexion;
            
            $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario";
            $usuario = $conexion->select($query);
            $usuario = $usuario[0];
            $this->id_usuario           = $usuario['id_usuario'];
            $this->nombre               = $usuario['nombre'];
            $this->apellidos            = $usuario['apellidos'];
            $this->usuario              = $usuario['usuario'];
            $this->contrasena           = $usuario['contrasena'];
        }
        
        function updateCorreo($correo)
        {
            global $conexion;
            
            $query = "REPLACE INTO correo SET id_usuario = $this->id_usuario, correo = '$correo'";
            return $conexion->update($query);
        }
        
        # Métodos estáticos
        
        public static function insertNomina($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo)
        {
            global $conexion;
            
            $query = "INSERT INTO nomina(id_usuario, puesto, sueldo)
                     VALUES($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo)";
            return $conexion->insert($query);
        }
        
        public static function insert($nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena)
        {
            global $conexion;
            
            $query = "INSERT INTO usuario(nombre, apellidos, usuario, contrasena)
                     VALUES('$nombre', '$apellidos', '$usuario', '$contrasena')";
            return $conexion->insert($query);
        }
    }
    ?>

insert.php
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Usuario.php");

extract($_POST);

$conexion = Database::getInstance();

$conexion->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_WITH_CONSISTENT_SNAPSHOT);

try
{
    $id_usuario = Usuario::insert($nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena);
    $id_nomina = Usuario::insertNomina($id_usuario, $puesto, $sueldo);
    $usuario = new Usuario($id_usuario);
    $updateCorreo = $usuario->updateCorreo($correo);
    $conexion->commit();
    echo 1;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $conexion->rollback();
    echo 0;
}
finally
{
    $conexion->close();
}
?>

Entonces la pregunta es, como puedo hacer para usar el objeto de la conexión $conexion en las funciones de la clase Usuario porque desde esas funciones es en donde mando llamar a las funciones de la clase Database.
O asi como tengo la variable global en cada función esta bien??

Te recomiendo que mires qué es un patrón Singleton. Resumiendo estás creando una instancia  única, y siempre una. Nunca tendrás dos! Aunque para implementarlo correctamente el constructor debería ser privado para que no pueda invocarse desde fuera. De esa manera tan solo se pueden crear instancias de este objeto a través del método getInstance() el cual si ya existe una no crea otra. De esta manera te garantizas que esta clase nunca se cree más que una vez y sea siempre la misma. El patrón usado no tiene nada que ver con extender una clase u otra :)

Singleton es una gran cosa, yo lo uso desde hace mucho y eso me permite saber que solo hay una única instancia de la clase que maneja la DB

Como ya han comentado los compañeros, se trata de un patrón Singleton y NO tienes que instanciar la clase con new(), sino simplemente incluir el archivo (si usas Autoloader mejor) y hacer algo parecido a:  $db=DbMySqli::getInstance(); con esto vas a tener una instancia única de la conexión siempre. En cuanto a extends mysqli, esto te permitirá usar todos los métodos de mysqli con esa instancia, sin tener que redefinirlos en la clase envoltorio. La respuesta que refieres es mía. Todavía se puede mejorar, adaptándola para un manejo de Excepciones que sea coherente ...

... Habría querido editar esa respuesta para mostrarlo, pero no he tenido tiempo sobre todo de probar un código funcional. En teoría, bastaría con poner un try ... catch en la conexión y desde el catch propagar la Excepción para manejarla en el contexto donde se usará la conexión. Esto no es obligatorio, pero conviene pensar desde el inicio en un manejo de Excepciones coherentes. Sin llegar a ese punto, no se puede considerar que un programa ha llegado a su madurez.

@A.Cedano de donde sale la variable $_instance?? Porque no la veo declarada en ninguna parte de la clase

Y ha que te refieres con new self()?? A la clase de la cual estás creando la instancia en este caso DbMySqli o a qué haces referencia??

$_instance es un error de typo,  debes cambiarlo por $mMysqli. Lo que hace new self es crear una instancia de la clase, en este caso, cuando la conexión no existe. En un contexto static como es el método getInstance, self hace referencia a la misma clase. Seria, en cierto modo, el equivalente a $this,  usada en contextos no estáticos.

@A.Cedano si entiendo bien entonces con new self() se hace referencia para tu ejemplo a la clase hija DBMySqli??

Correcto. Y al mismo tiempo, como esa clase extiende de la clase mysqli, puedes usar con esa instancia todos los métodos de mysqli sin necesidad de redefinirlos. A diferencia de que ahora deberás llamar a los métodos usando la notación: $laInstancia->elMetodo() y no $laInstancia::elMetodo(), porque en la clasemysqli esos métodos no son estáticos.

@A.Cedano ok entonces de acuerdo a ello hice unas modificaciones en el código que muestro en mi pregunta pero me surgió una duda.

Tu nueva duda da para escribir varios libros. Para intentar decirlo con palabras simples: en tu clase Usuario estás cometiendo un error de diseño al querer meter la conexión dentro. Una base de datos es una fuente de datos (puede haber otras) mientras que Usuario es una clase de entidad para representar a un usuario sin importar de qué fuente vengan los datos. Si tú metes la conexión dentro de Usuario estás pensando en corto, capando a esa clase y escribiendo un mal diseño. Aunque quizá ahora sólo obtienes los datos de la BD, mañana esos datos pueden venir de una API externa ...

... o de otro sitio. Por eso, la clase Usuario y todas tus clases del modelo deben permanecer independientes. Aplicando lo dicho, puedes reescribir los métodos sacando la conexión y en una fase intermedia (mientras migras a un diseño más flexible, usando por ejemplo repositorios de datos) puedes pasar la conexión desde fuera, a los métodos que trabajan con la base de datos. Así como quitar el SELECT del constructor y crear un método getById() que te devuelva a un usuario específico, pues tener eso en el constructor es otro error grave, porque no siempre que creas instancias de ...

... Usuario necesitas a un usuario por su Id. La clase Usuario debe servir para todo lo que necesites hacer con uno o más usuarios, desde obtenerlos todos, obtener algunos, crear instancias vacías para mapear un resultado proveniente de la misma base de datos o de otra fuente de datos, etc.

Si te interesa más adelante programar con una buena arquitectura y usando un diseño flexible, te dejo esta respuesta. A mi me ayudó bastante a escribir un diseño donde puedes acceder al modelo sin tener que meter la conexión dentro. Lo que se explica ahí es algo parecido a lo que usan frameworks como Symfony o Laravel, pero escrito en PHP puro. Si más tarde emigras a Symfony (ojalá lo hicieras algún día, lamento no haberlo conocido antes) o Laravel (basado en Symfony) u otro te será más fácil entender cómo funcionan internamente.

@A.Cedano he estado pensando en programar usando el patrón MVC de PHP pero primero quisiera terminar el proyecto así como lo he estado trabajando porque pues así he estado  con todos mis proyectos desde que me compartieron ese diseño, como dices puede que ese diseño no sea el más óptimo pero funciona y como te lo digo primero quisiera terminar mi proyecto para así tener algo funcional y de ahí migrar al MVC de PHP

En uno de tus comentarios dices que puedo pasar la conexión desde afuera a los métodos que trabajan con la base de datos, y eso lo haría pasando la conexión como parámetro o como??

Exacto. Los métodos de la clase Usuario que trabajan con la conexión tendrían un nuevo parámetro y quitas todos los global $conexion. Veamos cómo se definiría insert por ejemplo: public static function insert($conexion,$nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena){  //Cuerpo del método } Y para llamarlo: $id_usuario = Usuario::insert($conexion,$nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $contrasena);

En cuanto al constructor, lo dejas vacío: function __construct()         { } y creas un nuevo método llamado getById($conexion,$id_usuario) donde haces lo que ahora haces en el constructor. Esto dará flexibilidad cuando necesites crear instancias vacías de usuario. Además, puedes mapear resultados de consultas SELECT a la tabla usuarios a instancias de objetos de esa clase usando fetch_object() (significa que no tienes que asignar manualmente los datos) y para eso conviene que el constructor esté limpio.

Muchas gracias por tus respuestas pero si te aseguro que  muy pronto iniciare con el patron MVC de PHP
